# Error in training SVM model : Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: '2'

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I have the following data set( sample of 1st 10 rows given)

```
structure(list(variableA = c(11L, 7L, 17L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 4L), variableB = c(10L, 20L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), variableC = c(284L, 
43L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 20L), variableD = c(299L, 
24L, 28L, 167L, 167L, 27L, 27L, 194L, 194L, 21L), variableE = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), variableF1 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), variableF2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF6 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF7 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF8 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF9 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableF10 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableG1 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), variableG2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), variableG3 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), clusters = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), out = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("3", "1", "2", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

i have been trying to use the suppport vector machine algorithm on this data set, earlier it was working well now for some reason its giving the error.

model i am trying is

```
set.seed(111)
trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
svm_Linear <- train(out~`variableA`                   + `variableB`      +              
                      `variableC` +`variableD`+
                      `variableE`                           +`variableF1`            +
                      `variableF2`            + `variableF3`           +
                      `variableF4`            + `variableF5`           + 
                      `variableF6`            + `variableF7`           + 
                      `variableF8`            + `variableF9`           + 
                      `variableF10`            + `variableG1`                  + 
                      `variableG2`                   + `variableG3`  , data= train, method = "svmLinear",
                    trControl=trctrl,
                    preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                    tuneLength = 10)
svm_Linear
```

But I am getting this error which I am not able to understand.

```
Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: '2'
```

I saw a similar post on this site but none has the answer I required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `out` column is a factor with 6 levels, but only 3 are represented in the `dput` you provided in your post - that's why you're getting this error.

```r
levels(train$out)
# "3" "1" "2" "4" "5" "6"

unique(train$out)
# 3 1 6
# Levels: 3 1 2 4 5 6
```

This is probably due to the way you performed your train/test split .

You can redefine `levels(out)` to include only `c(1, 3, 6)`, but this will be a problem if your test data contains the other response levels.

Consider using a stratified sampling approach instead, to ensure your response variable is correctly represented across a train/test split.  Questions about stratified sampling would be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) than for Stack Overflow, but there are some good starting points mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776887/stratified-splitting-the-data).

Comment: got it.. thanks a lot. i will try this stratified sampling

Comment: i tried stratifed sampling as suggested by you and it worked awesome, now no errors at all